# Multivariable Calculus and application of implicit function theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

How can I solve b)?

> **Problem:** Let $f$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ by $$f(x,y)=2x^{3}-3x^{2}+2y^{3}+3y^{2}$$
> a) Find the four points in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ at which the gradient of $f$ is zero. Show that $f$ has exactly one local maximum and one local minimum in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

> b) Let $S$ be a set of all $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ at which $f(x,y)=0$. Find those points of $S$ that have no neighborhood in which the equation $f(x,y)=0$ can be solved for $y$ in terms of $x$ (or for $x$ in terms of $y$). Describe $S$ as precisely as you can.

**My attempt:** In a) we can see that $$\forall (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^{2}: \nabla f(x,y)=0 \iff (x=0 \quad \vee \quad x=1) \wedge \quad (y=0 \quad \wedge \quad y=-1)$$
Hence, $\nabla f(x,y)=(0,0)$ precisely at the four points $(0,0),(0,-1),(1,0),(1,-1)$.

Now, using of Hessian matrix we can see that $(1,0)$ is a minimum and $(0,-1)$ is maximum.

But, how can I solve b)? I think, I need to use implicit function theorem. But I don't know how to do it.

**New attempt:** We can see that  $$S=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^{2}: f(x,y)=0\} \iff S=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}: 2x^{3}-3x^{2}+2y^{3}+3y^{2}=0\}.$$So,$$ S=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}: (x+y)(2x^{2}-2xy+2y^{2}-3x+3y)=0\}$$Also, we can see that
$$\forall (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}: f(x,y)=0 \iff x+y=0 \quad \vee \quad 2x^{2}-2xy+2y^{2}-3x+3y=0.$$

So, we need to study

1. $y=y(x), x \in \mathbb{R}$.
2. $x=x(y), y \in \mathbb{R}$.

For the first case, we can see $f(x,y)=0$ iff $y=-x, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ or $2x^{2}-2xy+2y^{2}-3x+3y=0$, where we can solve this last equation using the *quadratic equation*, that is: $$y_{1,2}(x)=\frac{-b(x)\pm \sqrt{b^{2}(x)-4a(x)c(x)}}{2a(x)}$$where
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left\{ \begin{aligned} a(x)&=&2 \\ b(x)&=&3-2x \\ c(x)&=&2x^{2}-3x \end{aligned} \right.
\end{eqnarray*}
So, of the condition  $2y^{2}+(3-2x)y+(2x^{2}-3x)=0$, we can see that $$y_{1,2}(x)=\frac{-(3-2x)\pm \sqrt{(3-2x)^{2}-4(2)(2x^{2}-3x)}}{2(2)}=\frac{2x-3\pm \sqrt{9+12x-12x^{2}}}{4}$$where this equation has a real solution if, and only if, $$\Delta:= 9+2x-12x^{2}\geq 0 \iff \left( x- \frac{3}{2} \right) \left( x+\frac{1}{2} \right)\geq 0 \iff -\frac{1}{2} \leq x \leq \frac{3}{2}.$$

It's easy to see that $f\in \mathscr{C}^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{2})$ and for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ we have  $\nabla f(x,y)=(0,0)$ iff $x=0$ or $x=1$ and $y=0$ or $y=-1$. Since we are studying the case of $y = y (x), x \in \mathbb{R}$, then the *implicit function theorem* tells us that the only possible points near which *there might not be a unique solution* are where $ y = 0 $ or $ y = -1 $.

Now, let's study the cases $ \boxed{y = 0}$ and $ \boxed{y = -1} $. For this, we can see that
\begin{eqnarray*}
y=0 \iff \left\{ \begin{aligned}\frac{2x-3+ \sqrt{9+12x-12x^{2}}}{4}=0 &\implies x=0& \quad \vee \quad x=\frac{3}{2} \\ \frac{2x-3- \sqrt{9+12x-12x^{2}}}{4}=0 &\implies& x=\frac{3}{2}\end{aligned} \right.
\end{eqnarray*}
So the correspondent values of $x$ to $\boxed{y=0}$ are $\boxed{x=0}$ and $\boxed{x=\frac{3}{2}}$.
Also, we can see

\begin{eqnarray*}
y=-1 \iff \left\{ \begin{aligned}\frac{2x-3+ \sqrt{9+12x-12x^{2}}}{4}=-1 &\implies& x=-\frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{2x-3- \sqrt{9+12x-12x^{2}}}{4}=-1 &\implies & x= 1 \quad \vee \quad x=-\frac{1}{2}\end{aligned} \right.
\end{eqnarray*}
So, the correspondent values of $x$ to $\boxed{y=-1}$ are $\boxed{x=1}$ and $\boxed{x=-\frac{1}{2}}$.\
Let's now study all these different cases for the solutions $$\boxed{y=-x} \quad \boxed{y_{1,2}(x)=\frac{2x-3\pm \sqrt{9+12x-12x^{2}}}{4}}$$

But, I don't know how to continue from here

So, my approach is correct? is there another way for to solve this problem make it easier?

I don't understand the suggest of @ Ninad Munshi and @Eduardo Magalhães I don't know if there is something simple that I am overlooking.

Comment: "Solve for $y$" means that $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$ exists. Given the formula from implicit function theorem, when would it not exist?

Comment: Uhm... when $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}=0$?

Comment: I don't understand @Ninad Munshi. Can you explain me more?

Comment: I already explained enough, you didn't use the one formula I told you to look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a relationship between to variables expressed as: $$f(x_1,x_2)=0$$

Then you can easily find how one changes if you slightly change the other using the following formula:

$$\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_j}= -\frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}} {\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}}$$

For $i,j \in \{1,2\}$ and $i \neq j$

So, in you case where you want to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ the formula becomes:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}} {\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}}$$

In the problem, they are asking you to find the points where $\frac{dy}{dx}$ don't exists or where $\frac{dx}{dy}$ don't exist. That is simply the points where $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 0$ or where ${\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}}$. And that's how you solve the problem, you need to solve this two equations to find those points.

Comment: But, for example you can to do $f(x,y)=(x-y)(2x^{2}+2y^{2}-2xy-3x+3y)=0 \iff y=y(x) \vee 2x^{2}+2y^{2}-2xy-3x+3y=0$.

Comment: I was trying to solve this problem and I found the points $(0,0)$ and $(1,-1)$ the answers. Can you verify that?

Comment: But, I used a different method for to solve this problem and I don't know if there is a more easy way.

Comment: The points are $(0,0) , (0,-\frac{3}{2}), (1,-1), (1,\frac{1}{2}), (\frac{3}{2},0)$ and $(-\frac{1}{2}, -1)$

Comment: Ok. I got those points too, with the analysis I showed above. But the teacher says that answer to the problem b) the points are only $(0,0)$ and $(1, -1)$. But, I don't know how to justify that last part.

Comment: maybe he only wanted the points where both dy/dx and $dx/dy$ are both 0 @Ramanujan